# Get a cell that is in a table before the current table

Tags: xpath

See html below.  Have a series of tables that include rows with a name attribute name="laneStop".  I can select those rows like this in the Chrome dev console

```
$x("/html[1]/body[1]//TR[@name='laneStop']")
```

However, I also need to get the 2nd cell of the 2nd row of the 1st table ABOVE these rows, eg. the value

> abc_123_florida-45

Here is the html.  Whats a way to refer to this value above - knowing that Im getting the "laneStop" rows first

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Date</td>
                                                <td>11/15/2019</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>shipment number</td>
                                                <td>abc_123_florida-45</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Departure time:</td>
                                                <td>0430</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Time arrival</td>
                                                <td>1715</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>customer</td>
                                                <td>bob smith</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>box type</td>
                                                <td>square</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box1</td>
                                <td>23.45</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>south</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box2</td>
                                <td>17.14</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>south</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box3</td>
                                <td>17.18</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>north</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box2</td>
                                <td>199.14</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>west</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following xpath.

```
//td[text()='shipment number']/following::td[1]
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: This gets me a list of the rows with a 'shipment_number' but I need it relative to an individual 'laneStop' row which is in the table below it.

Comment: can you try this : `//tr[@name='laneStop']/preceding::table[2]//tr//td[contains(.,'shipment number')]/following::td[1]`

Comment: chrome dev console  - undefined

Comment: try on devconsol `$x("//tr[@name='laneStop']/preceding::table[2]//tr//td[contains(.,'shipment number')]/following::td[1]")[0]` and then hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to travel from your current node (i.e., the "laneStop" rows), one way to do that is to use this xpath expression:

```
./preceding-sibling::*/ancestor::*[6]/preceding-sibling::table[1]//tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]//td[1]//tr[2]/td[2]
```

I'm curious to see if it works for you.

Comment: Doesnt seem to resolve to a valid node, or maybe ive got a typo?
$x("/html[1]/body[1]//TR[@name='laneStop']")[1]./preceding-sibling::*/ancestor::*[6]/preceding-sibling::table[1]//tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]//td[1]//tr[2]/td[2]